# How to implement wifi for a headless IOT device?

Tags: iot

Recently I purchased a [TP-Link HS100 smart plug](http://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/cat-5516_HS100.html#overview) which I configured using an app and all is working well. Now I am trying to understand the underlying software and hardware architecture for such implementation. Based on simple google searches following is my understanding.

The headless smart plug makes a peer to peer connection to a device such as a mobile phone or computer. Using a device with a UI, network configurations are entered into the IOT device. The IOT device then connects to access point to make some type of authentication with a cloud service, and establishes a connection. The mobile app communicates the commands the cloud service which relays the command to the smart plug. This is pretty straight forward.

I like to understand a little bit deeper in both software and hardware architecture for this type of design. It is fair say that there is some type of wifi device like [CC3100](http://www.ti.com/product/CC3100) or similar. There is some type of microcontroller like an ARM Cortex. It could be an integrated wifi controller such as a [CC3200](http://www.ti.com/product/CC3200).

What is the underlying software and hardware architecture to implement similar microcontroller based design to setup and establish a secure communication link? What type of minimum security needs to implement to secure the device? I am hoping someone in this forum has experience in such an adaptation (2.4 GHz) and is willing to share their experience.

Comment: This question seems too broad to be answerable.

Comment: @jpa thank for the comment, all want to understand both Software and Hardware create a microcotroller base wifi communication link. I not interested in Linux (Rpi) type of operating systems based solution which I well known. Also any suggestion as to how to narrow the question of break the question into smaller chunks.

Comment: You might want to check https://www.softscheck.com/en/reverse-engineering-tp-link-hs110/